# Custom KML file in python

Tags: python, kml

I am trying to create a custom kml file that will create polygons for a flight. I have an excel file that has the mission number marked and includes 4 latitude, longitude points. I need to color these polygons depending on the status_text column in my excel file. I am struggling to add the proper latitude and longitude points.

```
import pandas as pd
from simplekml import Kml
import os 

excel_file = '433_ALL.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, engine='openpyxl')

bdf = df[['Mission', 'Long', 'Lat', 'Status_Text']]

bdf = bdf.set_index('Mission')
print(bdf.index)
uniq = pd.unique(df['Mission'])
poly_kml = Kml()


for val in uniq :
    lng = bdf.loc[bdf['Mission'] == val, ['Long']]
    lat = bdf.loc[bdf['Mission'] == val, ['Lat']]
    print(lng , ' ' , lat)
    poly_kml.newpolygon(name= 'Mission ' + str(val), outerboundaryis= [(lng, lat)])


poly_kml_path= os.path.sep.join(['..', '..', '4.33G', 'polyfile.kml'])

poly_kml.save(poly_kml_path)

os.startfile(poly_kml_path)
```

[excel file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzQYd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is how the Lat/Long columns in DataFrame are referenced. *Mission* column is an index in DataFrame so must reference it as `bdf.index` and not as `bdf['Mission']`. Next issue is the polygon *outerboundaryis* argument expects a list of tuples not a list with a vector of lats and a vector of lon values.

```python
poly_kml = Kml()
for val in uniq:
    lng = bdf.loc[bdf.index == val, 'Long'].tolist() # <----
    lat = bdf.loc[bdf.index == val, 'Lat'].tolist()  # <----
    coords = []
    for coord in zip(lng, lat): # <----
        coords.append(coord)
    poly_kml.newpolygon(name='Mission ' + str(val), outerboundaryis=coords) # <----
```

Also, if the data does not represent a closed polygon then you may want to create a [LineString](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) instead.

```
poly_kml.newlinestring(name='Mission ' + str(val), coords=coords)
```

Examples to add a Style to the generated KML can be found [here](https://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#polystyle).